# Blender->Unity materials problem

Tags: blender, uv-mapping, materials

I have a pproblem with materials and their texture. I have a model with 1 material called 'Car_Jack', after i put my .blend file into unity, unity adds 'Car_Jack__Car_Jack_UV', which is white material without textures. I have the only one UV map, called 'Car_Jack_UV'. What is wrong with Unity/Blender?
[image]

Comment: In Blender, is it actually a material on the object or just a texture that's been UV unwrapped to the model? You could probably open up the .fbx file (if it's non-binary) and look yourself to see if it's exporting the materials which will help you diagnose if it's Unity or Blender

Comment: Unreal engine reads all materials from this fbx correct with textures and so on. So it's 99% Unity fault. It's material with texture on it in Blender. And also unwraped.

Answer (score -1):

Try exporting your Blender scene as .fbx and import the fbx from Unity

Comment: I used .fbx too. Almost the same problem.